# Help identifying the manufacturer of a door by its sticker

Tags: doors

I have 4 steel entry doors on my house. 3 have matching stickers and 1 is the odd ball sticker but the door looks the exact same (for what it's worth). I'm hoping this amazing group can help identify the door brand by the sticker. I want to replace just the slab as replacing the package with side lights and transom is not needed (and $$$$).

The other three are Premdor Entergy doors. All fire doors for the garage.

Thank you for looking.

[image: Door Tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for "stl dr dksn std" returns results from Masonite, Jeld-Wen, and [STL](https://stlwindowsanddoors.com/door-company/).

Comment: Yes! I had just nailed this down after countless tries. Appreciate your getting to it quick!